# Undefined reference error while compiling C files with android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a bunch of `C` files with extensions `.c` and `.h`. I want to compile these files with `Android NDK`. When I tried with only one file, `NDK` worked perfectly, but when I tried including other files inside this main `C` files with includes, I get an error. What an I missing? This is my `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndksetupdemo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mymain_c_file.c
 LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := includes 
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Should I include anything more?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you only link against the log library (`LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog`).  If you are referencing functions that are not defined in any of the included headers and in your `mymain_c_file.c`, you will get the undefined reference error.  You will need to find out what other libraries you need to link against and list them in `LOCAL_LDLIBS`.

If the functions are defined in the other .c files, you need to add them to the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` variable.

Comment: Should I do like this LOCAL_SRC_FILES := mymain_c_file.c, secondfile.c

Comment: Separate files with spaces, not commas. It's standard GNU makefile format (Android.mk file actually is used as input to make program).

Comment: @MārtiņšMožeiko - indeed: I was too tired to catch that